# adding oracle's timestamp to query results

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

yesterday you had taught me to query record history within a time range [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359733/oracle-record-history-using-as-of-timestamp-within-a-range).

What more I need is to add oracle's (historical) timestamp to the results as a column. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in fact the answer to your previous question shows how:

```
SQL> select empno, sal, versions_starttime,versions_xid
  2  from emp
  3  versions between timestamp sysdate-1 and sysdate
  4  where empno=7369;

     EMPNO        SAL VERSIONS_STARTTIME                                                          VERSIONS_XID
---------- ---------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------- --
      7369       5900 11-DEC-08 16.05.32                                                          0014001300002A74
      7369       5800 11-DEC-08 16.03.32                                                          000D002200012EB1
      7369       5800
```

There is also a VERSIONS_ENDTIME pseudo-column.  Between them VERSIONS_STARTTIME and VERSIONS_ENDTIME bracket the period of time during which the change was made.

Comment: That would be a Toad problem.  Try SQL Plus.