# how to delete last record from a table in oracle database?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

how can we delete last record in a table in Oracle database,  if the date column is not present in the table.

Thanks,
Indrani

Comment: You need some column to generate an ordering by which we can say that a certain record is the "last" one in the table.  So, do you have such a column?

Comment: yeah thats what I wanted to know, if we do not have such column can we delete based on rownum column?

Comment: I don't know Oracle, but rownum is usually a contextual column based on the query, so no. Do you want the last record entered or the last record edited?

Comment: Thanks Alan, I want the last record entered to be deleted.

Comment: the only way would be to wind backwards through rollback segments using flash back, using some method of decremental timestamps, until the point you identify the last record inserted... this is only as good as how far back you can go backwards though.....

Comment: There is no such thing as "the last row of a table".

Answer (score 0):

you could try playing with this ability in oracle, if it is turned on in your database, and play with the times till the point you can find the second the last row was inserted.

```
select * 
from 
   (select * from emp)
AS OF TIMESTAMP SYSDATE - 1;
```

have a read of [Oracle record history using as of timestamp within a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359733/oracle-record-history-using-as-of-timestamp-within-a-range)